# Window length in Spark Structured Streaming

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

With Spark DStreams I can specify sliding Window length like this:

```
val windowedStream = stream.window(Seconds(20))
```

How to do this with Structured Streaming?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look to the window operation on event time documentation : https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#window-operations-on-event-time

Example :

```
val windowedCounts = words.groupBy(window($"timestamp", "10 minutes", "5 minutes"),$"word").count()
```